# Visually report progres

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So basically I want a control in which I add dynamically new lines, where every lines represent an operation that i'm doing. To achieve that i created a textbox like this one:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding CurrRow}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  AcceptsReturn="True"/>
```

and I update the CurrRow property in my view model as following:

```
for (index = 0; index < 100; index++)
{
    CurrRow = CurrRow + index.ToString();
    //various operation
    CurrRow = CurrRow + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

these is just an example to give the idea. The output is what I expected. However I would like something less "static" from visual perspective. For instance, i would like to add animated "..." within the line representing the  operation that is currently in work, and i don't know if the TextBox is the right choose in this context. So my question is : How can i make a "report viewer" in WPF?

Comment: Have you thought of using a `ListView`? Change CurrRow to a list of strings or whatever you need it to be and just add the items as you go. Befopre inserting a new valid info delete one that contains "...", this way it will show the task progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a MVVM example using a few libraries I personally recommend :

[image: Visual report progress demo demo]

View template (Xaml only):

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="Sandbox.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sandbox"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ProgressBar.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Button.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.CheckBox.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ListBox.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.PopupBox.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.RadioButton.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBlock.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ToggleButton.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="0">
            <ItemsControl
                MaxWidth="300"
                Margin="16,8"
                ItemsSource="{Binding LongTasks}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                            <ContentControl.Style>

                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFinished}" Value="False">
                                            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <DockPanel Margin="12">
                                                                <ProgressBar
                                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                                                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCircularProgressBar}"
                                                                    Value="{Binding Progress}" />
                                                                <TextBlock
                                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDisplay1TextBlock}"
                                                                    Text="Task running" />
                                                            </DockPanel>
                                                        </DataTemplate>

                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </DataTrigger.Setters>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock
                                                    Margin="12"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDisplay1TextBlock}"
                                                    Text="Task finished" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="12"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Command="{Binding AddLongTask}"
            Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=Plus,
                                              Size=32}"
            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```

Key point here you seem to want is to use a `DataTrigger` to change a `ContentControl`'s `ContentTemplate` based on your condition so you can display something completely different.

The ViewModel to emulate the long run tasks in background :

```cs
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Sandbox
{

    public class SandboxNotifiableViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> projection)
        {
            var memberExpression = (MemberExpression) projection.Body;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(memberExpression.Member.Name);
        }

        public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
            => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public class TestViewModel : SandboxNotifiableViewModel
    {
        private class SandBoxCommand : ICommand
        {
            private readonly Action cbk;
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

            private void WarningRemover()
                => this.CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            public SandBoxCommand(Action cbk)
            {
                this.cbk = cbk;
            }

            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
                => true;
            public void Execute(object parameter)
                => this.cbk?.Invoke();
        }

        public TestViewModel()
        {
            this.AddLongTask = new SandBoxCommand(this.AddLongTaskAction);
            this.LongTasks = new ObservableCollection<LongTaskViewModel>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<LongTaskViewModel> LongTasks { get; }

        private void AddLongTaskAction()
            => this.LongTasks.Add(new LongTaskViewModel());

        public ICommand AddLongTask { get; } 
    }

    public class LongTaskViewModel : SandboxNotifiableViewModel
    {
        private bool isFinished;
        private int progress;


        public LongTaskViewModel()
        {
            this.Progress = 0;
            this.IsFinished = false;
            // Refresh progress every 10ms 100 times 
            Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10))
                .Select(x => x + 1) // 1 to 100
                .Take(100)
                // Here we make sure observable callback is called on dispatcher thread
                .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                .SubscribeOnDispatcher()
                .Subscribe(this.OnProgressReported, this.OnLongTaskFinished);
        }

        public bool IsFinished
        {
            get => this.isFinished;
            set
            {
                this.isFinished = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int Progress
        {
            get => this.progress;
            set
            {
                this.progress = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }

        }

        public void OnProgressReported(long dummyval)
        {
            this.Progress = (int) dummyval;
        }

        public void OnLongTaskFinished()
        {
            this.IsFinished = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I used [Rx.NET](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) to handle async notifications (here progress emulation) and [MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) for the global styling